# 'Zend_Http_Client_Exception' with message 'Passed adapter is not a HTTP connection adapter

Tags: api, zend-framework, upload, youtube

This is making my crazy. I really hate to post questions but "here goes".

I was able to upload a video using the Zend Gdata API for You Tube. "One video"...

Ever since I have received this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Http_Client_Exception' with message
'Passed adapter is not a HTTP connection adapter'
in ../pathtoapp/Zend/Http/Client.php:926

Stack trace:
    #0 ../pathtoapp/Zend/library/Zend/Gdata/HttpClient.php(275): Zend_Http_Client->setAdapter(Object(__PHP_Incomplete_Class))
    #1 ../pathtoapp/Zend/library/Zend/Gdata/App.php(692): Zend_Gdata_HttpClient->setAdapter(Object(__PHP_Incomplete_Class))
    #2 ../pathtoapp/Zend/library/Zend/Gdata.php(219): Zend_Gdata_App->performHttpRequest('POST', 'http://uploads....', Array, Object(Zend_Gdata_MediaMimeStream), 'multipart/relat...', NULL)
    #3 ../pathtoapp/Zend/library/Zend/Gdata/App.php(910): Zend_Gdata->performHttpRequest('POST', 'http://uploads....', Array, Object(Zend_Gdata_MediaMimeStream), 'multipart/relat...')
    #4 /home/spotya/public_html/devblogpost/php/Zend/library/Zend/Gdata/App.php(985): Zend_Gdata_App-> in ../pathtoapp/Zend/library/Zend/Http/Client.php on line 926
```

Similar posts I found have solved the issue, but their solutions have not worked for me.

My Code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once('Zend/Loader.php');
require_once('../../includes/defines.php');

Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_HttpClient');
$client = new Zend_Gdata_HttpClient();

$developerKey = '';
$applicationID = '';
$clientID = '';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `you_tube_credentials` WHERE `user_id` = '1'";
$auth = $db->FetchAssoc($db->Query($sql));
if($auth['id'] == '') // If Auth Key not stored in DB get one
{
        $authenticationURL= 'https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin';
        Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');
        $httpClient = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient(
                          $username = '',
                          $password = '',
                          $service = 'youtube',
                          $client = null,
                          $source = 'My Videos', // a short string identifying your application
                          $loginToken = null,
                          $loginCaptcha = null,
                          $authenticationURL
                       );
    $httpClient_ser = serialize($httpClient);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `you_tube_credentials` (`user_id`,`user_name`,`password`,`application`,`developer_key`,`http_client`)
                        VALUES
            (1,'social@spotya.com','XXXXXXX','Spotya Videos','".$db->Escape($developerKey)."','".$db->Escape($httpClient_ser)."')";
    $db->Query($sql);
    header('location: youtube.php');
}
else
{
    $httpClient = unserialize($auth['http_client']);
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `video_cue` WHERE `posted` < 4 AND `post_datetime` < '".date('Y-m-d H:i:m')."'";

$result = $db->Query($sql);
while($row = $db->FetchAssoc($result))
{
    $transactionid = time();
    Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_YouTube');


    $yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube($httpClient,"Spotya Videos",$clientID,$developerKey);

    // create a new VideoEntry object
    $myVideoEntry = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry();

    // create a new Zend_Gdata_App_MediaFileSource object
    $filesource = $yt->newMediaFileSource(realpath('/pathtovideo/video_auto_upload/'.$row['file_name']));
    //$filesource = $yt->newMediaFileSource(realpath('Wildlife.mp4'));

    $filesource->setContentType('video/mp4');
    // set slug header
    $filesource->setSlug($row['file_name']);

    // add the filesource to the video entry
    $myVideoEntry->setMediaSource($filesource);

    $myVideoEntry->setVideoTitle($row['title']);
    $myVideoEntry->setVideoDescription($row['description']);
    // The category must be a valid YouTube category!
    $myVideoEntry->setVideoCategory('Education');

    // Set keywords. Please note that this must be a comma-separated string
    // and that individual keywords cannot contain whitespace
    $myVideoEntry->SetVideoTags($row['tags']);


    // upload URI for the currently authenticated user
    $uploadUrl = 'http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads';
    // try to upload the video, catching a Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException, 
    // if available, or just a regular Zend_Gdata_App_Exception otherwise

      $sql = "INSERT INTO `video_post_log` (`transactionid`,`sent`,`status`)
          VALUES ('".$transactionid."',
                  '".$db->Escape(serialize($myVideoEntry))."',
                  'Initialized')";
    $db->Query($sql);
    try
    {
        $result = $yt->insertEntry($myVideoEntry, $uploadUrl, 'Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry');
    }
    catch (Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException $httpException)
    {
        $result = $httpException->getRawResponseBody();
    }
    catch (Zend_Gdata_App_Exception $e)
    {
        $result = $e->getMessage();
    }

    if(is_array($result) == true || is_object($result) == true)
    {
        if(strpos($result,'xml') === false)
        {
            $result = serialize($result);
        }
    }
    $sql = "UPDATE `video_post_log` SET `result`= '".$db->Escape($result)."',`status` = 'Complete' WHERE `transactionid` = '".$transactionid."'";
    $db->Query($sql);
    $sql = "UPDATE `video_cue` SET `posted`=`posted`+1 WHERE `file_name` = '".$row['file_name']."'";
    $db->Query($sql);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this in the stack trace:

```
Zend_Gdata_HttpClient->setAdapter(Object(__PHP_Incomplete_Class))
```

Notice how it says it is passing a `__PHP_Incomplete_Class` object to `setAdapter`.

My guess is that when you pull the object from the database and unserialize it, the class that you are unserializing is not loaded, which is why it becomes a `__PHP_Incomplete_Class` object.

Try adding this code before you attempt to unserialize the HTTP client from the database:

```
else
{
    Zend_Loader_Autoloader::autoload('Zend_Gdata_HttpClient');
    $httpClient = unserialize($auth['http_client']);
}
```

By preloading the class, when you call unserialize, it should come out as a `Zend_Gdata_HttpClient` instead of the incomplete class.

In case that doesn't work, try to also load `Zend_Http_Client` since that is what `Zend_Gdata_HttpClient` extends from.

**EDIT:** Also try using the newer autoloader; replace:

```
require_once('Zend/Loader.php');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_HttpClient');
```

with:

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
$autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance(); // this sets up the ZF autoloader

Zend_Loader_Autoloader::autoload('Zend_Gdata_HttpClient');
```

Comment: Hmmm... Zend_Loader_Autoloader not found error, but clearly Zend_Loader_Autoloader is in Zend/Loader.php.

Comment: Are you using Zend_Application or Zend Framework standalone and just picking the component you need?

Comment: Well, a reference to it within the deprecated registerAutoLoad anyways. I'll search around and see if I can find anyone else with this error.

Comment: Not sure actually. I don't have "any" experience with Zend. I am using Zend's Gdata version 1.11.12. And whatever flavor is contained within.

Comment: I just made an edit, looks like you are using just the Gdata stuff standalone

Comment: I couldn't find Autoloader.php located anywhere in the Zend library folder. So I downloaded the latest minimal version of the Zend framework. I copied the necessary folder to my library directory. Now Its.. well I can at least communicate with the server, and its returning an XML error. "validation code too short". Thanks for your help, it really saved my skin. I think I can take it from here.

Comment: FYI for anyone who get 'validation too short'. You Tube requires 'Title','Description','Tags'. I was testing using tags, "this,is,a,test". "a" was too short to be considered a keyword. Upload is working now.